# Searching for a sequence in String which is a combination of constant+variable

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have a String S = "AA AA BB :1 CC :2 DD :30 EE :149";

How can I loop on the String S and 1 by 1 grab each of the numbers starting with : and save them in an Int ?

E.g.

```
 int holder;
    String S = "AA AA BB :1 CC :2 DD :30 EE :149";
    // Loop Start

    holder = s.Grab1stnumberstarting with :
    System.out.println(holder);

    // Loop End
```

So that I get the output:

```
:1
:2
:30
:149
```

Comment: Use a regular expression?

Comment: You can use regex, the regex `:\d+` and `find()` to iterative search for ints, see http://fiddle.re/h4m7b , use `String#SubString` to remove the `:`, and parse it as `int`. Try something and if you have problem, ask it here!, but try first!.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "AA AA BB :1 CC :2 DD :30 EE :149";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
:1
:2
:30
:149
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex pattern using [*Positive Lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/fA9dM4/1)

sample code:

```
String s = "AA AA BB :1 CC :2 DD :30 EE :149";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=:)\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    int number = m.group()
    System.out.println(":"+number);
}
```

Regex pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is
    :                        ':'
  )                        end of look-behind
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (most possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion, and to avoid *now having two problems*, this can easily be achieved without using regular expressions:

```
String s = "AA AA BB :1 CC :2 DD :30 EE :149";
String[] parts = s.split(" ");
for(String part : parts) {
    if(part.startsWith(":")) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}
```

*This assumes that the desired output is anything beginning with a `:`, not just numbers, though could easily be uplifted to find only numbers.*

Comment: And assumes that the separator is a `" "` (space).